# Fall-off of Klein-Gordon massless field in flat spacetime (proof from Wald)

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, klein-gordon-equation, asymptotics

In Wald's General Relativity (1984) he devotes one of the last chapters to asymptotic flatness. He starts by showing how the conformal compactification of Minkowski spacetime can be used to determine the falloff behaviour of fields. I'm confused about the proof he gives for the proposition 11.1.1 in that chapter:

[image]

The proof follows immediately after:

[image]

If I understand correctly, it just uses the fact that we can set up initial data on the Cauchy surface $T=0$ in the conformal compactification of Minkowski space, including spatial infinity $i^0$ at $T=\pi$. Then by uniqueness he claims that there exists a solution $\tilde{\phi}$ in the conformal compactification (including the boundary) and that going back to the original Minkowski spacetime gives the corresponding falloffs. **I'm a bit confused about this last step and how to check the falloffs since he never does this last step nor he actually checks falloffs.**

Comment: I do not have the textbook with me now. But the idea is simple. Consider the behaviour of $\Omega$ close to the null infinity. $\tilde\phi$ Is finite and smooth approaching that hyper surface…

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply. So what you are saying is that since $\tilde{\phi}$ is finite and smooth approaching the conformal boundary, then the fall off of $\phi$ will only be given by the factor $\Omega$ since $\phi=\Omega \tilde{\phi}$? I'm still unsure about how to think about the behaviour of $\Omega$ close to the boundary, though.

Comment: Yes you have understood well. The expression of $\Omega$ is explicitly written in Wald's book, just check...